# How to search a number JSON array in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a `JSON` in my `MYSQL` like [1,2,3].

And how can i get where 1 is.

I tried to use this:

```
SELECT  JSON_SEARCH('[1,2,3]','one',1);
```

But the result of this is NULL

I expect the output to be `$[0]`

Comment: please show json structure

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON array elements should be in double quotes:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '["1","2","3"]' AS json
)

SELECT
    json,
    JSON_SEARCH(json, 'one', '1')
FROM yourTable;
```

This returns `"$[0]"` for the match of `'1'` against the JSON text.

### Demo

As to why it doesn't work with number literals (which should in fact be valid literal JSON values), it seems that the third parameter to `JSON_SEARCH` is a search *string*, and it only works against actual text, not numbers.

Comment: So is there a function that can search for numbers?

Comment: Good question +1.  I don't know.  Maybe someone else can post a solution which would work.